# spring cloud stream keep kafka socket connection alive

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

I need to configure the spring-cloud-stream Kafka socket alive because of losing the connection to the Azure EventHub. 
Based on the recommendation page
 https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md
I need to set the `socket.keepalive.enable` to **true** but I can't find the configuration to set in spring-cloud-stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a `librdKafka` configuration option (for C/C++); it has nothing to do with the Java clients.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944737/how-to-recover-from-exceptions-sent-by-producer-send-in-spring-cloud-stream solved my issue